# Use Multi Model in View

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller

Please help me to use Two Model in MVC View.

I have used the bottom lines, But it still doesn't Work:

```
@using HelpDesk.Models;

@model Tuple<IEnumerable<Ticket>, IEnumerable<Order_List>>
```

And This is my Error In Red Page:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[HelpDesk.Models.Login]', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Tuple`2[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[HelpDesk.Models.Ticket],System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[HelpDesk.Models.Order_List]]'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a Tuple you can create a new ViewModel that contains both the objects, like a container.

Like This:

```
public class BothViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Order_List> Orders { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your View, you can use the new ViewModel(BothViewModel)

```
@model BothViewModel
```

Hope this helps.